# Nested component state control

Tags: react-native

I have an overlay/modal within a screen that resides under a parent container that I would like to control as follows:

1. On load, visibility is false
2. When user performs and act on the screen/container component, the overlay shows.
3. The user can close the overlay by clicking on the area outside the overlay (onBackdropPress)
4. Data within the overlay is provided by the parent container (through state).

Should I generate a state within the screen component and assign props to it?

```
class Screen extends Component {
  state = { visible: this.props.visible, data: this.props.data }
  render () {
    return (<Overlay isVisible={this.state.visible} onBackdropPress={this.setState({visible: false})}><Text>{data}</Text></Overlay>)
  }
}
```

How do I deal with the problem that by setting the state within the Screen component, the parent container's state is not updated yet?

Visibility is still set to true in the parent container even though it's already set to false in the screen component.

```
<Screen visible={this.state.visible} data={this.state.data}>
```

Comment: Can you show me the full code?